# Add counter to ID names in dynamically added rows

Tags: javascript, count, addition, element, dynamically-generated

Here is part of a function that adds rows. It works like a charm, except I'd also like it to add an integer (+1) to the ID names of each newly created set of elements.

For example, the code below generates a row, a cell, and a button. If three rows are created, then I'd like the button ID's to be **foo1, foo2, foo3** for each row, respectively.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

```
function addrow() {
var i = 1;
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
var row = table.insertRow(1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='button' id='foo+i' value='Hello'>";
i++;}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='button' id='foo" +i + "' value='Hello'>";`

Comment: use `var i = 1; function addrow() { .... cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='button' id='foo"+i +"' value='Hello'>"; i++; }`

Comment: Excellent answers, I'll update my structure and the globally declare my variable outside of the function. Thank you all so much.

Comment: @john-ruddell I'd love to but sadly my reputation is below 15 at the moment.

Comment: you should be able to accept the answer no matter what your reputation is since its your question. thats strange... i'll give you an upvote though :)

Comment: my mistake -- I accepted it, I'm just too new to vote up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='button' id='foo+i' value='Hello'>";
```

to:

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='button' id='foo" + i + "' value='Hello'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concat the string with your incremented variable, not place it inside the string.

```
"<input type='button' id=foo" + i +" value='Hello'>"
```

But there is more you need to do...
You need to make your `i` variable be global so it isn't reset every time you call this function like so

```
var i = 1;
function addrow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable"),
        row = table.insertRow(i),
        cell1 = row.insertCell(i);
    cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="button" id=foo' + i + ' value="Hello">';
    i++;
}
```

I also changed the quotes around since a single quote isn't considered valid syntax for HTML

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='button' id='foo+i' value='Hello'>";
```

to

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='button' id='foo"+ i +"' value='Hello'>";
```

And initialize `i` value as global variable.

Use

```
var i = 1;
function addrow() { 
  var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='button' id='foo"+i +"' value='Hello'>"; 
  i++; 
}
```